# The File is not writing to the Document Directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, download

// I am trying to download file from google drive i am able to list file in nslog with  its size but not able to write in document Directory. Currently It save a pathwith extension but not saving the original file.

```
GTLDriveFile *file;
NSString *downloadedString = file.downloadUrl; // file is GTLDriveFile
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.driveService.fetcherService  fetcherWithURLString:downloadedString];
filename=[[NSString alloc]init];


[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)     
{
 GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n");    
    NSLog(@"This is File Size=====>%@",file.fileSize);

    NSLog(@"This is file Name===>%@",file.title);

    if(file.downloadUrl!= nil)
        {

       filename=file.title;    

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename]];
[data writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


    NSLog(@"my path:%@",documentsDirectory);
    }
    else
    {
    NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.description);
    }
}];
// ya i got it...
 NSString *downloadURL=[[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] downloadUrl];
 GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =

 [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadURL];
```

Comment: you want to save in you document directory ??

Comment: ya correct in document directory...

Comment: check `filename` is correct or not by nslog

Comment: it is correct...i checked it shows size description ..

Comment: @iPatel...i have checked..yar it working good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// I have tried this.. it is working for me...

```
 NSString *downloadURL=[[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] downloadUrl];
 GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =

 [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadURL];

 filename=[[NSString alloc]init];   

 [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)

 {
    GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",file.fileSize);
    NSLog(@"%@",file.title);

    if(file.downloadUrl!= nil)
        {

          if (data!=nil) 

            {
       filename=file.title;    

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename]];

 [data writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];

  NSLog(@"my path:%@",documentsDirectory);

   }
   }
   else
   {
        NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.description);
    }
   }];
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be as below, see my comments in ALL CAPS.

```
GTLDriveFile *file;
NSString *downloadedString = file.downloadUrl; // file is GTLDriveFile
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.driveService.fetcherService  fetcherWithURLString:downloadedString];
filename=[[NSString alloc]init];


[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)     
{
 GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //THIS LINE IS WRONG

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n");    
    NSLog(@"This is File Size=====>%@",file.fileSize);

    NSLog(@"This is file Name===>%@",file.title);

    if(file.downloadUrl!= nil)
        {

       filename=file.title;  // THIS IS CORRECT  

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename]];

//USE DATA TO WRITE THE FILE NOT `documentsDirectory`
[data writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];


    NSLog(@"my path:%@",documentsDirectory);
    }
    else
    {
    NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

**Edit**

Too you can refer to this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/DriveSampleWindowController.m?#691)

Comment: [data writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; in data getting error No Visible interface for Nsdata declare the selector writeToFile

Comment: Oh sorry it should be `writeToFile:<#(NSString *)#> atomically:<#(BOOL)#>` instead

Comment: it saving only only some kb of data from my code...so plz check my code

Comment: yes your code is saving, but not data, it is saving `documentsDirectory` because you are using the variable as data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35347/discussion-between-james-ryan-and-iphonic)